# ASP: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, database, subquery

I have a website hosted locally, with a MS SQL Server Database. I'm trying to populate a list of records from the database, but the query is returning an error.

Code on asp webpage:

```
dim sRegID

sRegID = Request.QueryString("RegistrantID")
sSQL = "select CourseID, CourseSectionID, RegistrationID, RegistrantCourseID,AmountDeferred,PaymentType,  DateSubmitted, (select TransactionID  from qryRegistrantCoursePayment where RegistrantCourseID = qryRegistrantCoursedetail.RegistrantCourseID) as TransactionID, (select PaymentID  from qryRegistrantCoursePayment where RegistrantCourseID = qryRegistrantCoursedetail.RegistrantCourseID) as PaymentID from qryRegistrantCourseDetail where RegistrationStatus in ('D') and RegistrantID = " & sRegID & " and AmountDeferred > 0  order by DateSubmitted"
Set rs = objconn.execute(sSQL)
```

Error Message:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Can someone help me out with this? I'm not very experienced in query writing. Thanks in advance. :)

---

Ok the query was fixed with a join... But now the asp is acting up.

```
Else
Response.Write "<table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0>"
Response.write "<tr>"
Response.Write "<td>" & "<a href=""javascript:pick('','','','','','','','','')"">" & "None Selected" & "</a></td>"
Response.write "</tr>"
Do Until rs.eof

 Response.Write "<tr>"
 'Response.Write "<td>" & "<a href=""javascript:pick('" & trim(rs("BLDG_CD")) & "')'>" & trim(rs("AC_Title")) & "</a></td>"
 Response.Write "<td>" & "<a href=""javascript:pick(" & quote(trim(rs("q.RegistrationID"))) & "," & quote(trim(rs("q.RegistrantCourseID"))) & "," & quote(trim(rs("q.CourseID"))) & "," & quote(trim(rs("q.CourseSectionID"))) & "," & quote(trim(rs("x.PaymentID"))) & "," & quote(trim(rs("q.AmountDeferred"))) & "," & quote(trim(rs("q.PaymentType"))) & "," & quote(formatdatetime(trim(  rs("q.DateSubmitted") ),2)) & ",'" &  trim("" & rs("x.TransactionID")) & "')"">" & formatcurrency(0 & rs("q.AmountDeferred"))& "</a></td>"
 Response.Write "</tr>"
```

Error Message:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'
>
> Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested
>   name or ordinal.

I'm not able to comprehend why the Error is ADODB whereas I've used

```
Set rs =objconn.execute(sSQL)
```

Thanks again for any help possible.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, the two subqueries `(select TransactionID ...` or `(select PaymentID  ...` are returning more than one row (e.g. your data model allows for more than one payment per course per registrant?).

Although you can work around this by introducing the subqueries with a `TOP 1`, it would be beneficial to determine why the data doesn't behave as your are expecting:

Also, because both subqueries act on the same table with the same predicate, you can change the subquery into a derived table and join to that, instead:

```
select
  CourseID, 
  CourseSectionID, 
  RegistrationID, 
  RegistrantCourseID,
  AmountDeferred,
  PaymentType,  
  DateSubmitted, 
  x.TransactionID,
  x.PaymentID
from qryRegistrantCourseDetail 
    cross apply
    (select TOP 1 TransactionID, PaymentID
     from qryRegistrantCoursePayment
     where RegistrantCourseID = qryRegistrantCoursedetail.RegistrantCourseID
     ) AS x
where ...
order by DateSubmitted
```

If you resolve why the subquery returns more than one row, you can then change to a simple join:

```
inner join qryRegistrantCoursePayment as x
    on x.RegistrantCourseID = qryRegistrantCoursedetail.RegistrantCourseID
```

[SqlFiddle of both queries here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80b1d4/5)

Comment: Thanks Stuart.

This was due to some special case which allowed more than 1 record(specifically, 2). 

Will a join work if I need to display both records? If yes, how do I modify the current query?

Comment: Yes, if you use the JOIN directly, then it will return both records. I've updated with a SqlFiddle showing both

Comment: Thanks again. The query seems fins but now the asp is acting up.

`code'

Comment: Thanks again. The query seems fins but now the asp is acting up.

I've updated the question above... Please have a look at it. :)

Comment: Just remove the alias (q. and x.) from the field names in asp rs("TransactionId") etc. Aliases are needed in SQL to resolve ambiguity but are nit part of the resultant column names :-D